# When new data loads masonry js not reloading (Masonry JS and Handlebars)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, jquery-masonry

I am using Handlebars http://handlebarsjs.com/ and Masonry https://masonry.desandro.com/ to get some JSON data and add it to the dom every 5 mins using Jquery prepend.

The problem I am having is the first time I add the data to the dom Masonry works fine and displays horizontally

eg.[image]

but 5 mins later when the new data gets added it just drops it vertically. It is supposed to prepend and move the other elements across.

eg.[image]

function to add to dom.

```
function AddToDom() {
   console.log("AddToDom");
   setTimeout(function() {
     cardContainer.prepend(compiledCardTemplate(model)).masonry({
       itemSelector: '.grid-item',
       columnWidth: '.grid-item',
       // percentPosition: true,
       horizontalOrder: true,
       fitWidth: true
     });
   }, 1000);
}
```

I am using setTimeout as a delay from the retrieval of data to adding to dom.

edit:
After suggestions from Ali, I tried this

```
function AddToDom() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let $items = compiledCardTemplate(model);
    cardContainer.append($items).masonry('prepended', $items);
  }, 1000);
}
```

but I am getting this error

```
masonry not initialized. Cannot call methods, i.e. $().masonry("prepended")
```

edit: for clarity

```
let cardContainer = $(".wrapper");
let cardTemplate = $("#card-template").html();
let compiledCardTemplate = Handlebars.compile(cardTemplate);

let model = {
 posts: []
}
```

edit: called functions

```
 // docuemnt init
 $(document).ready(function () {
   GetData();
   AddToDom();
   setInterval(AddToDom, 50000);
 });
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with code below (Many thanks to @riyza-ali)

```
function AddToDom() {
 setTimeout(function () {

   let items = compiledCardTemplate(model);
   let $items = $(items);

   let grid = wrapper.masonry({
     itemSelector: '.grid-item',
     columnWidth: '.grid-item',
     horizontalOrder: true,
     fitWidth: true
   });

   grid.prepend($items).masonry('prepended', $items);

  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(AddToDom, 50000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `cardContainer` is a [Masonry Grid](https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html), to add to the start (*prepend* to start) more items to the Grid you need to call [`Masonry#prepended()`](https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#adding-removing-items).
The above snippet can be written as:

```
function addToDOM(model) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var $item = $(compiledCardTemplate(model));
    $cardContainer
      .prepend($item)  // to prepend to DOM node
      .masonry('prepended', $items); // to notify masonry
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Yes, cardContainer is the div wrapper for masonry grid. model is an array object  
    let model = {
      posts: []
    }

Comment: Also, compiledCardTemplate(model) is handlebars which adds the post to the dom

Comment: Ohk! then you simply need to compile (or convert) your model into some kind of HTML repr. and wrap it in a jQuery object.

Comment: let cardContainer = $(".wrapper");
let cardTemplate = $("#card-template").html();
let compiledCardTemplate = Handlebars.compile(cardTemplate);

Comment: Masonry doesn't care from where (and how) you get your data... so as long as jQuery is happy with the data (it's valid HTML) you're good to go and can use any library (handlebars etc.) to get your HTML... You just need to notify `masonry` about the action using `Masonry#prepended()` method

Comment: regarding `.masonry('...'  /* args */)`  syntax... This is a jQuery UI inspired function call syntax... nothing fancy about it...

Comment: Ok, let me try it. Thank you.

Comment: let $items = compiledCardTemplate(model);
      console.log($items);

      cardContainer.append($items).masonry('prepended', $items);  I tried this but its just dropping it vertically. Apologies I am relatively new to JS

Comment: I am getting this error in the console <masonry not initialized. Cannot call methods, i.e. $().masonry("prepended")>

Comment: You need to make the function call on an initialised masonry instance... like your `$cardContainer`